# tscがtsconfig.jsonを使用してくれない。

Tags: typescript

TypeScriptでSymbolを使ったコードを書いたのですがtscがtsconfig.jsonに基づいてコンパイルしてくれないためにエラーが発生してしまいます。

以下がTypeScriptのコードです。

main.ts

```
let symbol = Symbol();
```

ここで、`tsc main.ts`コマンドをコマンドラインに入力すると、

```
error TS2585: 'Symbol' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to es2015 or later.
```

というエラーがでました。

`tsc -init`でtsconfig.jsonを生成し、以下のように編集しもう一度同じコマンドを入力しましたが結果は同じでした。（libオプションにes6を指定した。）
tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",                               
    "lib": ["DOM","ES6"],                                   
    "strict": true,                                 /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                        /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                           /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true        /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

tscがtsconfig.jsonを使用せずにコンパイルしようとしているのではないかと思い、`tsc main.ts -lib "es6"`と入力するとちゃんとコンパイルが通りました。

このことから私はtsconfig.jsonが使用されていないと思いました。。

`-p`オプションでtsconfig.jsonをして指定してすると、うまく動くという情報を目にしたので試してみたのですがそれもうまくいきませんでした。(`tsc -p tsconfig.json`)

どうすればtscがtsconfig.jsonの内容に基づいてコンパイルしてくれるのでしょうか？

ちなみにtscはグローバルインストールしています。

### バージョン

tsc: 4.3.5

### 構成

```
./
├── main.js
├── main.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

Comment: [Using tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#using-tsconfigjson-or-jsconfigjson) を読みますと **When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored.** と書かれています。

Comment: tscコマンドではコンパイルするファイルを指定しつつ、tsconfig.jsonを適用してコンパイルするという方法が用意されていないということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、そうなります。

Comment: 全くもってお勧めできる方法ではありませんが、tsc コマンドの本体である [tsc.js](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/tsc.js) を改造すれば可能です(2行削って3行追加)。

Comment: 追記部分については元の疑問と内容が少し異なるので、別の質問として他に質問くださるとよさそうです。